# Top alignment in tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

I'm trying to update my CV using an overleaf template, and the template sets out "education" items in a table, according to the code snippet below. I would like the text in all columns (in particular the right hand column) to be top aligned, but the `[t]` doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I make this top aligned?

What I have
[image]

[image: What I want[![enter image description here][2]][2]]

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand*{\cventrymsci}[4]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
      \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#1} & \entrylocationstyle{#2} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#4} & \entrydatestyle{#3} \\}
    %\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `[t]` aligns the table as a whole with text on the same line but your table is full width so has nothing on the same line so `[t]` does not do much. The alignment of text within the cells depends on code you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the code for where I believe the column styles are defined, if more context is needed I'll create a link to the project

Comment: well as I suspected you used `m` instead of `p` But in general you should always post complete small documents that show the problem and allow answers to be tested, not whole projects and not disconnected fragments.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, if you post it as an answer I’ll mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `m` for vertical centred columns, you want the default `p` column type for top aligned parboxes.